# ValueError using itertools.zip_longest (fillvalue)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have the following code and face two problems.

```
import itertools

data_1 = [(1, '1', '2', '3'), (2, '4', '5', '6')]
data_2 = [(1, '7', '8', '9')]

for (a, b) in itertools.zip_longest(data_1, data_2, fillvalue="----"):
    p = (a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3])
    print("p", p)
    value1 = float(p[1])+float(p[2])+float(p[3])
    print("value1", value1)
```

My first problem is that when I use fillvalue="----" then it's work. Why not its work when I use fillvalue="-"?

My second problem is that when I add an extra line (value2 = float(p[4])+float(p[5])+float(p[6])) below the line value1 the its give the following error message:

value2 = float(p[4])+float(p[5])+float(p[6])
p (2, '4', '5', '6', '-', '-', '-', '-')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'

What is my soluation, How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, think about what "zip_longest" does. It is like the `zip()` function but will not terminate if it reach to the end of shortest iterator, instead it continues the end of the longest and fill the shorter ones with the `fillvalue`.

The error you get when you specify `fillvalue="-"`:

Your first iterator is `data_1` with one item and second is `data_2` with two items inside. `b` gets items from `data_2` after unpacking. In the second iteration, it gets the `fillvalue` which is `"-"`. The point is `"-"` is now actually your whole `b` and there is only one character so you can't do `b[1]`, `b[2]` and etc.

I think you get the idea about your second question. In the second iteration(when you use `"----"`), although you can get the items `p[4]`, `p[5]` and ... it can't convert `"-"` to float.

Comment: please give me an idea how can I sum float(p[4])+float(p[5])+float(p[6])

Comment: @MohammadYasin In the first iteration, you can. but in the second iteration , as I said the reason, you can't. The error you get is in the second iteration. try to run the code line by line with debugger, you will see it.